# Where are the users personal dashboards in dynamics mscrm stored in the DB?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I need to get all personal dashboards in db I looked at tables:`UserQuery, UserFormBase, UserQueryBase, UserQueryVisualizationBase, SavedQueryVisualizationBase`
found nothing. In `systemform` table I found dashboard but not personal.
Where is this treasure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in `UserFormBase`, you may get more detail [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/reference/entities/userform)

I tested both online and on-premise.